# how to redirect to new screen when we get response from api in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Hello I am developing application in react-native where I will get some response from api.Based on the response I want to divert to respective screens.If there is  error in response will divert to error page else success page.
So I am using [react-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/).
so here's my code I call method to get response from api

```
 get_response(){

fetch(GET_DATA_URL_ONE,
{
  method: 'post',
  header:{
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson)  => { 
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

    var cde = responseJson.result;
    for (var i in cde) {
      var abc = cde[i].seats;
      for(var j in abc)
      {
        myData1.push(abc[j]);
      }
    }
    var maxvalueRow = Math.max.apply(Math, myData1.map(function(o) { return o.column; }));
    // alert("maxvalueRow="+maxvalueRow)

    var maxvalueColumn = Math.max.apply(Math, myData1.map(function(o) { return o.row; }));
    // alert("maxvalueColumn="+maxvalueColumn)
   // numColumns = maxvalueColumn+1;
   global.maxCols=maxvalueColumn+1;


   //I get Alert here When I run But Not redirecting to next screen Don't Know why
    alert("global.maxCols="+global.maxCols)

      this.props.navigator.push({
        screen: 'awesome-auth.Confirmation',
        title: 'Confirmed',
        subtitle: Name,
        passProps: {maxvalueRow,maxvalueColumn},
        Style: {
            backgroundColor: '#000000',
            tintColor: white,

        }
      });

})
 .catch((error) => {
     alert("Eror "+error)

  })


}
```

Comment: Did you registered `awesome-auth.Confirmation` with Navigation.registerScreen ?

Comment: Have you used this code? this.props.navigation.navigate('[your error screen]', this.state);

Comment: Hey @Reza sir even that's not working I tried.

Comment: Hey @rm-rf. sir I have register it already but even though it not diverting. Can we have like same as async task in android which has  post execute and pre execute methods

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have implemented  Navigator, which is a component that manages all stuff related to screens. In your current screen, you need to implement -

> this.props.navigation.navigate('Desired screen name')